# How can I create a client side database

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, sqlite

How can I create a client side database to store information of users on client side. Does anybody know of any tutorials or pointers? Which is the recommended database to use? My client is in `.js` and uses `Django` framework.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is called [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) and is part of HTML5.

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage.html

However, many times when people SAY they need a client-side database, I ask them the details and it turns out that they don't really need client side storage at all, so proceed with caution.